# Proper way to update HTML5 offline application cache

Tags: javascript, html, html5-appcache

I use offline caching in my website and have the following event handler setup to handle updates

```
applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', function () {
                    if (window.applicationCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY) {
                        window.applicationCache.swapCache();  
                        window.applicationCache.update();
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                });
```

It works but seems redundant to me. Do I need to call the swapCache() and update() functions or will a simple window.location.reload() suffice since the browser will use the new files on a refresh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually according to MSDN documentation about [Application Cache API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh771716(v=vs.85).aspx) you should use both.

From the documentation:

> In order to swap an old cache out for a new one, call update first.
>   When the status is in the UPDATEREADY state, calling swapCache will
>   make the swap.
>
> Calling swapCache will not update any content on your page. It will
>   simply allow your webpage to be able to access any further dynamic
>   content from the new cache instead of the old one. After the page is
>   refreshed, the newly created cache will be used for all in-page and
>   dynamic requests.
>
> The swapCache method is provided for convenience but is not necessary
>   for basic functionality. Loading or refreshing the page is sufficient.
>   For example, refreshing the page after an UpdateReady event will
>   reload the page from the new cache without a call to swapCache.
>
> swapCache does not cause previously-loaded resources to be reloaded;
>   for example, images do not suddenly get reloaded, and style sheets and
>   scripts do not get reparsed or reevaluated. The only change is that
>   subsequent requests for cached resources will obtain the newer copies.